# JQuery tablesorter not working in xhtml

Tags: jquery, xhtml, tablesorter

I'm trying to use the JQuery tablesorter plugin, but for some reason it works in HTML and it doesn't work in XHTML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                   <![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#myTable").tablesorter();
            });
            //]]>
                </script>
   </head>

    <body>

        <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Heading column 1</td>
                    <td>Heading column 2</td>
                    <td>Heading column 3</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>Z</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>

    </body>
```

This file named test.xhtml and loaded locally with Firefox and Internet Explorer shows the following behaviour: Clicking on any header cell with sort the table according to the content of the FIRST column. But what is intended is that it the table is sort according to the content of the column below the heading clicked.

As soon as I re-name the file into test.html and remove the CDATA-Tags the tablesorter works fine as expected.

For some reasons I have to produce XHTML. So, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to ask the tablesorter developers if it's compatible with XHTML. The only differences I could imagine would involve the `<tbody>` elements - HTML always has an implied tbody, XHTML doesn't need one; this results in differences in DOM trees - but as you explicitly provide one, there shouldn't be any differences in what Javascript routines have to work with.

Comment: By the way, your javascript routine doesn't need any CDATA blocks, as it doesn't contain any "risky" characters.